# Get all values in a JSON dictionary, without accessing by key

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, dictionary

JSON Example:

`[{
"title1":"Hey",
"title2":"Hoh",
"title3":"Hah",
"title4":"Hoo"
}]`

How can I get value `(hey,hoh,hah,hoo)` without using `valueForKey`?

Could anyone guide me please?

--------------Edit--------------

I use JSON-Framework. And Now I use NSDictionary *jsonDict = [string JSONValue];

Comment: What JSON parsing framework are you using?

Comment: And if you post some sample code, it should be possible to see what data structures you are using. If you have an NSDictionary with those keys you can try [yourDict allValues] . This returns an NSArray to you which you can loop through as you normally would (or use some string magic to concatenate it with a glue string).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have your data in an NSDictionary, try `allValues`.

Remember however than an NSDictionary is unsorted, so the order of the values is undefined.

Comment: Could you explain me more ? Where I should use allvalue ??

Answer (score 2):

As Todd already said, NSDictionary has a method allValues - check the [NSDictionary Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

An example of looping through the value's is

```
for(NSString *value in [jsonDict allValues]){
NSLog(@"Found Value %@",value);
}
```

Again, these values will be unsorted as they are coming from a dictionary.

Comment: Please note: that link is for Mac OS not iOS